# Martingale convergence in $L^\infty$

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Let $(\Omega,(\mathcal{F}_n)_n,\Bbb{P})$ be a filtered probability space and let $(X_n)_n$ be a discrete time martingale which is bounded in $L^\infty$, say
$
\|X_n\|_\infty\leq 1
$ for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$.
Martingale convergence theorems apply and show that $X_n$ converges almost surely to some (bounded) random variable $X_\infty$, and $X_n$ converges to $X_\infty$ in $L^p$ for any $p\in[1,+\infty)$:
$$
X_n\xrightarrow{~\Bbb{P}\text{ a.s.}~}X_\infty,~
X_\infty \text{ is essentially bounded and }
\forall p\in[1,+\infty),~
X_n\xrightarrow{~L^p~}X_\infty
$$
[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3014134/11258) shows that convergence need not happen in $L^\infty$. Are there general results that imply $L^\infty$ convergence?

Comment: Do you have a particular example in mind?  $X_{n} \to X_{\infty}$ in $L^{\infty}$ if and only if there is a deterministic sequence $(\epsilon_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converging to zero such that, with probability one, $|X_{n} - X_{\infty}| \leq \epsilon_{n}$ for all $n$.  This is *almost* like asking that $X_{n} = X_{\infty} + \delta_{n}$ for some deterministic sequence $\delta_{n}$, and then I guess $X_{n}$ can't be a martingale unless $(\delta_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \equiv 0$

Comment: There are simple cases where we have convergence in $L^\infty$ such as the one from the link in the OP ($X_n=\mathbf{E}[f\mid\mathcal{B}_n])$ where $\mathcal{B}_n$ is the sigma algebra generated by the $[k2^{-n}, (k+1)2^{-n})$ and $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ is continuous (or more generally it would seem if $f$ is the uniform limit of step functions, i.e. regulated). I have an example in mind that I haven't worked out at the moment of a bounded martingale where almost sure convergence defies my intuition (although it must be true, of course, on top of all $L^p$ convergences, $1\leq p<+\infty$.)